# Getting full branch coverage in equals() method with EclEmma

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, equals

This is tedious, but I've got an assignment where I need to achieve full coverage of the equals() method to earn all possible points. I'm having issues getting full statement/branch coverage due to the getClass() portion of the equals() method. So far I've gotten 1/2 branches covered, but I can't get my mind around how to get to the second.

Equals method below:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        //Lots of other tests checking the functionality of the program that I've figured out already
        return true;
    }
```

The unit test that is getting me 1/2 branches covered:

```
assertFalse(!s1.getClass().equals(s1.getClass()));
```

Since I've gotten 1/2 branches covered I assume the second is possible. But idk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;` considers two instances to be **different if both are not instances of the same class**. For example, when `obj` is an instance of a class that extends the class of `this`, even if all fields have the same value.

So you also have to compare s1 with a s2, that is an instance of a class that extends the class of s1 to get here the `return false;` branch executed.

Please note, that in `assertFalse(!s1.getClass().equals(s1.getClass()));` your `equals` method is not called, but `java.lang.Class::equals` and that `assertFalse(!...)` is the same as `assertTrue(...)`.

Comment: So is there another way to do this if the class I am testing the equals() method for does not extend into a different class? I am relatively new to programming so there may be a way to do this without creating another class (an extension class is not defined in project structure). I have tried creating an instance of a String class and testing that with the statements: String string = "String";
  assertFalse(s1.getClass().equals(string.getClass()));

Comment: You'd have to clarify what "does not extend into a different class" means.

Comment: @J.B.Good Unfortunately. your question does not show the class in which the `equals` method is. Assuming it's in `Foo` (having a default constructor) and your test is named `FooTest`, then in `FooTest` create the inner class `static class Bar extends Foo { }` and do `assertFalse(s1.equals(new Bar()));`.

Answer (score 0):

Some information you've left out is what class the "s1" object is, and what class this equals method is in.  It's reasonable to assume that "s1" is of the same type as the class your "equals" method is defined in.

Under that assumption, the line in question (converted to the simpler version alluded to by @howlger):

```
assertTrue(s1.getClass().equals(s1.getClass()));
```

Is not even executing your "equals" method.  That's because you're calling "s1.getClass().equals(...)" instead of "s1.equals(...)".

An assertion that would actually be testing your code would be more like this:

```
assertTrue(s1.equals(s1));
```

To address your coverage question, this obviously by itself would not give you full coverage in the method.  It will match the first "if" and return true.

Assertions that should give you closer to complete coverage would include these:

```
// s1 and s2 are different instances of the same class, with identical contents
assertTrue(s1.equals(s2));
// s1 and s2 are different instances of the same class, with different contents
assertFalse(s1.equals(s2));
// s1 and s2 are different instances of different classes
assertFalse(s1.equals(s2));
```

In addition, it's useful to note that you can run your test in the debugger, with breakpoints in the "equals" method, to verify exactly what path the code takes.